# use of <file> tag in layout?

Tags: layout, theme, helper

> `<file>` tag in layout file.

I have use one third party extension. In their layout file they have use the below code.

```
<action method="addJs">
     <file helper="rewardssocial/purchase_share/getJs" />
     <script>tbt/rewardssocial/purchase/share/reward.js</script>
</action>
```

I don't know what the purpose of the **file** tag in that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets start from `<action method="addJs">`.

This is the same as calling

```
Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addJs()
```

But if you take a look at methods signature, you will see that it has two parameters.

```
public function addJs($name, $params = "")
```

That means that content of tags

```
 <file helper="rewardssocial/purchase_share/getJs" />
 <script>tbt/rewardssocial/purchase/share/reward.js</script>
```

will be passed as `$name` and `$params` values. Name of tags here means nothing.

Order  is only important.

`<file>` tag has no content. But has `helper` attribute, which tells that the result of helper method execution will be passed as first attribute value.

So as a result this xml is equal to.

```
Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addJs(
    Mage::helper('rewardssocial/purchase_share')->getJs(),
    'tbt/rewardssocial/purchase/share/reward.js'
);
```

Also you can specify parameters which can be passed to your helper

```
<file helper="rewardssocial/purchase_share/getJs">
    <arg>Now with arg!</arg>
    <!-- more args here -->
</file>
```

This is equal to

```
Mage::helper('rewardssocial/purchase_share')->getJs('Now with arg!')
```